# Interleaved 2 of 5 Barcode - Aumentar o tamanho da string no parâmetro

Tags: java

Bom dia, amigos!

Estou com um problema na hora de passar a String com o código de barra no parâmetro do BarcodeInter25 , Neste código está funcionando mas caso eu passe "23797685200000345000280090000014189301107610" ele gera uma Exception de java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The text length must be even.

E eu já procurei varios tipos e não acho o ideal, já que meu projeto precisa gerar um barcode para boleto bancário com 44 posições do formato ITF.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            try {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:\\BarcodesInter25.pdf"));
                document.open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

                BarcodeInter25 code25 = new BarcodeInter25();
                code25.setGenerateChecksum(true);
                code25.setCode("99-1234567890-001");
                Image image25 = code25.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);

                document.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(image25, 0, 0)));
            }
            catch (Exception de) {
                de.printStackTrace();
            }
            document.close();
      }
```

Obrigado !

Comment: Não tenho como testar aqui, mas acredito que você tem que configurar o tamanho de 44 como um tamanho permitido na biblioteca, seria algo assim: `Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<DecodeHintType,Object>(); hints.put(DecodeHintType.ALLOWED_LENGTHS, new int[]{44});`

Comment: @Math, esse projeto não permite que eu faço qualquer tipo de alteração e nem inclusão na biblioteca padrão. Já tentei usar o Barcode128 e BarcodeEAN, todos eles geram um código de barra diferente do tipo ITF

Answer (score -1):

"The text length must be even."
Significa que a quantidade de números que você deve passar tem que ser ímpar.
Este é um problema que temos com essas bibliotecas prontas. Ela não aceita que você passe o digito verificador. Mas se você não passa, ele gera o código errado, sem o dígito. O jeito é fazer tudo na mão, observando as instruções passadas pelo banco para gerar o digito verificador na posição correta, pois na linha digitável ele está em uma posição diferente da impressa no código de barra. Você tem que criar sua própria barra, convertendo valor, vencimento, código do cedente, etc...

Comment: *"The text length must be even"* = *"O tamanho do texto tem que ser **par**"*.